# MySQL query stuck on this

Tags: mysql

Here's the question: Bryce Sanders has joined The Bullets, although he also remains a member of The Neurotics. Update the database accordingly, using only one statement.

Here's what I have so far:

```
 update xrefartistsmembers 
 set artistID = (
     select artistID from artists where artistname=  "The Bullets"
 )  
 where memberID = ( 
     select memberID 
     from xrefartistsmembers 
     where memberiD) = (select memberID from members where firstname = "bryce");
```

So This doesn't work..and I cant upload an image, or i would upload my database picture...let me know if you absolutely need the database image.

EDIT!: HEre's a pic of the database: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3ZiU.jpg

Comment: Knowing what "The bullets" and "The Neurotics" represent would be great. If they are both artists, how are you meant to represent the change if he is meant to be part of both?
A simple mention of the columns available would also be nice if they are helpful.

If you tell us what you want to change in one statement then it would make it easier for us

Comment: I suspect what you want is an insert, since you shouldn't change his current membership, just add a new one.

Comment: I agree Joachim. That seems the most resonable solution.

Comment: I've updated with an image, which should be much more helpful. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Insert into xrefartistsmembers (ArtistID, MemberID, RespParty)
SELECT art.ArtistID, memb.MemberID, xref.RespParty FROM Members memb, xrefartistsmembers xref, Artists art 
WHERE memb.FirstName='Bryce' AND
memb.LastName='Sanders' AND
memb.MemberID= xref.MemberID AND
art.ArtistName='The Bullets';
```

This should help you. :) Let me know any changes you want.

If there are any problems, let me know.

In my answer I have no idea what respparty is. I simply copy it from previous entries. (This may cause some problems, but you have the general Idea down.

Answer (score 0):

try that:

```
 where memberID  in (select memberID from members where firstname = "bryce");
```